# loop structure in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Thanks for answering the previous question had before, i did the following, but i am trying to execute this loop, but there is no error given. I am trying to do date difference.

```
In[7] = Import["testA.txt", "Table" , "HeaderLines" -> 1]
Out[7] = {{100, 2010, 2, 20, 2010, 8, 30}, {110, 2010, 4, 30, 2010, 9, 
           12}, {112, 2010, 8, 20, 2010, 10, 28}}

In[10] =  For[i = 1, i < 4,   
          i = i + 1, {a = Out[7] [[i, 2]], b = Out[7] [[i, 3]],   
          c = Out[7] [[i, 4]] , d = Out[7][[i, 5]], e = Out[7][[i, 6]],   
          f = Out[7][[i, 7]], DateDifference[{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}]}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  For[] doesn't generate an output.  The differences you wanted to computer were computed (191, 135, and 69) and the results weren't written or stored anywhere.  To make this evident, rewrite your DateDifference[] call to `Print[DateDifference[{a,b,c},{d,e,f}]];`.

Without any further hints about what you wanted to happen.  It's not clear how to provide any more advice.  You could Sow[] and Reap[].  You could Join[] the result of DateDifference[] to a results List.  You could print the difference (as described above).  You could assign the results to some variable(s), define a symbol to take their values of specific inputs, et c., et c., et c...

-- EDIT --

Oh, and to address some of the other respondents, the *correct* form of this code is:

```
    foo = Import["testA.txt", "Table" , "HeaderLines" -> 1];
    diff[in_List] := Join[in[[Range[2, 7]]], {DateDifference[in[[Range[2, 4]]], in[[Range[5, 7]]]]}]
    diff /@ foo
```

Output is: `{{2010, 2, 20, 2010, 8, 30, 191}, {2010, 4, 30, 2010, 9, 12, 135}, {2010, 8, 20, 2010, 10, 28, 69}}` (and you probably want to assign that somewhere also).

Comment: Yes, the Range[]s can be replaced with shorter syntax.  However, transforming code into line noise doesn't improve readability.

Comment: Span syntax is useful here:  `Join[in[[2;;7]], {DateDifference[in[[2;;4]], in[[5;;7]]}]`

Comment: @Joshua Martell:  I recommend reading the comment I posted before yours.

Comment: while I agree, in principle, about the line noise, I don't believe that `Span` contributes to it overly much.  For the most part, `in[[2;;4]]` is as clear as `in[[Range[2,4]]]` because `2;;4` can be read as 2 through 4.  There are cases where it would be more difficult to read, like the equivalent `2;;-4`, but here it is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Since, you seem to want to process each list element individually, I'd use [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html?q=Map&lang=en) (or its short form `/@`) for this, as follows.

```
In[1]:=data = {{100, 2010, 2, 20, 2010, 8, 30}, 
               {110, 2010, 4, 30, 2010, 9, 12}, 
               {112, 2010, 8, 20, 2010, 10, 28}};
       #~Join~{DateDifference[#[[2;;4]],#[[5;;]]]}& /@ data
Out[1]:={191, 135, 69}
```

Mathematica is primarily a functional programming language, so while constructs like `For`exist, it is usually better to think in terms of functions operating on and transforming expressions.  Often, if you need a procedural process like `For`, [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Table.html?q=Table&lang=en) is a better bet.

My code has one slight disadvantage, the lack of named variables can be a pain sometimes.  In this case, however, they are not necessary.  But, if you need them there are several constructs that could be used [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/With.html?q=With&lang=en), [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Block.html?q=Block&lang=en), [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html?q=Module&lang=en), or even [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html?q=Function&lang=en).

Answer (score 3):

### Warning: This is not the way to go

This is your program corrected and running. I am posting it because I saw may conceptual errors in your code and I thought that having a running version for comparing it with yours may help you to identify them and learn.

Some points:

- Use of common constructs (Length@x, i++, etc)
- Don't use "Out[n]=" ... Never use capitals as first char of a variable name
- Learn how to construct lists (see the AppendTo)

Here is a running code:

```
x = Import["testA.txt", "Table" , "HeaderLines" -> 1]

ret = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length@x, i++,
  AppendTo[ret,
    {a = x[[i, 2]],
     b = x[[i, 3]],
     c = x[[i, 4]],
     d = x[[i, 5]],
     e = x[[i, 6]],
     f = x[[i, 7]],
     DateDifference[{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}]}
    ];
  ];
Print@ret
```

But as I said THIS IS NOT THE WAY TO GO. Read and study (and run in debug!) rcollyer's answer for understanding how to do it right in Mathematica.

BTW, You could replace the For loop by a Table (see rcollyer's suggestion)

```
Table[
      {a = x[[i, 2]],
       b = x[[i, 3]],
       c = x[[i, 4]],
       d = x[[i, 5]],
       e = x[[i, 6]],
       f = x[[i, 7]],
       DateDifference[{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}]}, {i, Length@x}]
```

Comment: you misread his code, which I did initially, also.  His intent is to return the original data with the `DateDifference` appended.  So, he wrapped everything in braces to make it a `List`.  Naive, yes, but effective.  Excepting, of course, his lack of a `Print` statement.  Now if he was only interested in the `DateDifference`, then you are absolutely correct.  But, his prior question suggests otherwise.

Comment: Or, more correctly, the iterator should be `{i, Length @ x}`. ;)